# How to add conditions in Typeorm for conflict when use onUpdate

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

In my project I use NestJS, TypeOrm and Postgresql.

I have entity:

```
@Entity('books', { schema: 'public' })
export class Book  {
  @PrimaryColumn('character varying', { name: 'id', length: 64 })
  public id: string;

  @Column('character varying', { name: 'name', length: 64 })
  public name: string;

  @Column('boolean', { name: 'is_locked', default: false })
  public isLocked: boolean;
}
```

I need to insert new rows and, in case of conflict, update only those rows where is_locked = false.
Now I use this query:

```
await this.booksRepository
          .createQueryBuilder()
          .insert()
          .values(books)
          .onConflict(
            `("id") DO UPDATE SET "name" = CASE WHEN books.is_locked THEN books.name ELSE excluded.name END`,
          )
          .execute();
```

Use of onConflict syntax is deprecated.
I want delete deprecated syntax.
But I don't understand how I should implement orUpdate for my case.
Maybe someone has ideas? Thanks.

Comment: hi @Ursus, please update if you have found an answer. I'm with the same challenge